# Email delivery status

Tags: email, email-bounces

I am trying to [track an email](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_tracking). I use mutt so that I can edit the email headers directly before sending, and I added:

```
X-Confirm-Reading-To: me@email
Disposition-Notification-To: me@email
Return-Receipt-To: me@email
```

to the header of a test email to gmail.com. Alas, nothing happened although I at least expected a [DSN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounce_message).

Am I missing something, or are these just supported poorly?

Comment: Mail to me will never give such a response. I find such requests quite obnoxious. Are you going to follow up with "you received my email, why haven't you responded?"

Comment: In certain situations it is good to know that my email made it at least to the receiving server. I understand that a Read Receipt is client dependent, can be blocked, and is thus unreliable. But nevermind my intention, what about the support for those headers?